# HeaderView and Footer view does't added to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I cannot attach header or footer, tried different examples.
Layout of my fragment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My empty_header layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="254dp" />
```

My fragment class code:

```
public class ListTestFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView mListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_test, parent, false);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
            "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone", "Linux", "Windows7",
            "Eclipse", "Suse", "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" };
        View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_header, null);
        View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_header, null);
        mListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        mListView.addFooterView(footerView);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And no single effect take place, just listView of items on screen displayed.

Comment: Post your `empty_header.xml` file content.

Comment: Added emty_header.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the parent when inflating:

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_header, mListView, false);
```

Comment: Kind of weird, but in exmples I used it works without parent specifying. Thanks.

Comment: @KonstantinBerkow I find it weird too. It works with a `TextView` but not with other type of views I tried.